# Using DB_LINQ for PostgreSQL and C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, dblinq

Dear..
I want to use postgresql as database and when I was do google I found Db_Linq to connect postgresql as LinQ.
But when I install it, I confused how to do it..
First, I download solution and compile and then I type it on command prompt 
DbMetal.exe \server:localhost:5432 /user:postgres /password:admin /database:testdatabase /code:linqGen.cs provider:Postgresql 
but it`s not work..
Can Someone give me a hint how to install Db_Linq?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: "it's not work" is far too vague. Please give more details.

Comment: Try to follow this instruction(has video) http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/10/nhibernate-orm-how-to-object-relational.html Try NHibernate 3 it now has Linq provider, sample code: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/performing-order-by-on-distinct-on-linq.html. I've tried DbLinq before, I don't have much luck with it, some queries that run on Linq-to-sql doesn't run on DbLinq. Try NHibernate 3's Linq

Comment: An example for Fluent NHibernate http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/nhibernate-3-fluent-linq-one-stop-shop.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are more required parameters than you can expect. F.e --language and --code are required. Anyway, use --debug parameter to see exact errors, then google them )